# Rotating an image 90° at the origin of the coordinate system

Tags: android, opencv

I want to rotate image by 90 degrees and keep the image in positive part of coordinate system. I am using code below:

```
val center = Point(imageHeight.toDouble()/2, imageWidth.toDouble()/2)
val rot = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 90.0, 1.0)
```

But unfortunately image is rotated in way that part of it lays in negative x and y axes. It looks like it has some offset added. Is there any way to have this rotation matrix without this offset?

Thanks!

Comment: What about cv2.rotate?

Comment: After rotating image I need to transform also some points related to image. That's why I wanted to use RotationMatrix.

Comment: You don't need a rotation matrix for that. The formula is simply (x, y) => (height-y, x)